# Android project update and how to solve: "Failed to resolve: monitor"?

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

Because of problem that jcenter() remove some older libs I decide to update my project.
So now I have:

```
 gradle: 4.6
```

and:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

I almost solve every dependency but I get

```
Failed to resolve: monitor
```

without any clue what is that monitor ;(

Comment: I have already answered the question at the following link. Check it and do let me know if that solves your error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52992335/9494420

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Same for me. It works If I comment espresso libraries and:

> androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
>     androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'

I´ve found a solution. Put google() at the beggining in

> `buildscript {
>   repositories {
>       google()`

and

> `allprojects {
>     repositories {
>       google()`

in project gradlew

Answer (score 4):

On my project, when I **remove** the dependencies:

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

This error is gone.
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I suffered the same issue due to espresso-core.
However I resolved the issue.
Try to change your build.gradle as given below:-

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find another post solve the issue, here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/52981328/4172325

I choose Solution 1 as it supports Android Test.